# Is there any way of redirecting user from In-app browser like Instagram to Google Chrome browser using JavaScript or Python in Android?

Tags: javascript, python, android, django, instagram

I'm trying to make my website redirect from Instagram to Google chrome.

This is my JavaScript try to redirect url, but it is not working as I thought:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.includes("Instagram")){
      window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank');
}
```

And in python I've tried using `webrowser.get("google-chrome").open("https://www.google.co.in/")`, but both methods do not work for me!
Please help! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method on my PC. Maybe if you register the path for the browser than it can work.

```
import webbrowser as wb 
browserpath = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe'
wb.register('edge', None, wb.BackgroundBrowser(edgepath))
wb.get("edge").open(https://www.google.co.in/)
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible for a website to get the path of chrome browser in android.

Comment: Is there any way?

Comment: In the file system you can fin the path, but I don't know if it will work or not.

Comment: Okey, I tried my code. Without the registration part it says that it didn't find the browser. (Because it tries the PC path, i think). So if you can find the path for the browser, than it should work I think.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this question.

Comment: Your welcome and good luck with it. If you could solve it with my method than please accept my answer.